# Timer.periodic is not cancelled when the condition is true

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous

I"m using a method that checks if the user's email is verified every 5 seconds, the `checkIsEmailVerified()` is asynchronous since it needs to send a request to check if the user has verified his email.

```
      void checkEveryDurationUserVerification() {
       Timer.periodic(
        Duration(seconds: 5),
          (timer) async {
            if (isUserVerified) {
              timer.cancel();
           }
      print("another check");
      await checkIsEmailVerified();
      },
    );
  }
```

so here is what happens, when this method is executing, it shows `"another check"` every 5 seconds as I want, and so the `checkIsEmailVerified()`.

so what I have ? is a fully working email verification checker every 5 seconds, and the email is not verified yet.

when I open my email inbox and verify my email, **In the app it works the listener I gave to the `isUserVerified` is working because it's `true`, and it navigates me to the home page as I want, but the Timer is not canceled even the `isUserVerified` is `true`**

**The `"another check"` is still printing in the debug console**, even if the `isUserVerified` is `true` and so it should cancel that `Timer`**

**what I think:**

that this behavior is related to making the `Timer`'s callback asynchronous

**what I expect:**

I want the when the `isUserVerified` is true the Timer to be canceled, so it stopped working after verifying the user

Comment: I don't see anything that prevents your code from accidentally creating multiple periodic `Timer`s (which is by far the most common mistake I see people making with periodic `Timer`s), in which case cancelling one would not affect other outstanding `Timer`s.  Have you verified that you're creating only a single periodic `Timer`?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, and everything works fine, I'm setting in a listener that when isUserVerified  is true, navigate to home page. and this is what'h happening so isUserVerified is true

Comment: but the timer is still running and print is working so even isUserVerified is true, every 5 seconds the times runs again

Comment: How did you verify that there are not multiple `Timer`s?  Can you provide a minimal, reproducible example?  You haven't shown enough code here to tell what you're doing wrong.

Comment: because my entire app so far, use one timer

Comment: That's not what I mean.  `Timer.periodic` creates a new periodic `Timer` every time it's called. What prevents your app from calling `checkEveryDurationUserVerification` multiple times?  What prevents it from creating a new periodic `Timer` when one already exists?

Comment: oh actaully this information is new to me, thank you

Comment: but the Timer is put inside the initState so it's called just one time

Comment: And is your `Widget` ever constructed more than once during the lifetime of your app (e.g. when navigating back and forth between pages)?  Since you never save a reference to the periodic `Timer` object you created, that means you currently never cancel it when your `State` object is disposed of.

Comment: Oh yes I see what's wrong now, it's like you say

Comment: thank you jamesdlin, I appreciate it really